# Python ctypes to np.dtype conversion of bitfields

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I am recieving a bytestring from a server which I'm trying to decode. I've managed to figure out the ctypes structure (see code), but it contains bit fields.

What I usually do is just use the np.frombuffer function to obtain the data as this recognizes most ctypes. Additionally I can write the data to HDF5 files without the need for any more manipulation. Due to the bitfields however, the dtype size and ctype size do not match and the data is converted, but plain wrong. You should be able to run the code below as is.

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np

#%%
class SubStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [('bUnderrange', ctypes.c_ubyte, 1),
                ('bOverrange', ctypes.c_ubyte, 1),
                ('bLimit_1a', ctypes.c_ubyte, 1),
                ('bLimit_1b', ctypes.c_ubyte, 1),
                ('bLimit_2a', ctypes.c_ubyte, 1),
                ('bLimit_2b', ctypes.c_ubyte, 1),
                ('bError', ctypes.c_ubyte, 1),
                ('TXPDO', ctypes.c_ubyte)] #This is a byte, rest are bits

class MainStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 4
    _fields_ = [('stStatus', SubStruct),
                ('nValue', ctypes.c_ushort),
                ('fValue', ctypes.c_float)]

rawdata = b'X\x00W\x00ff\x86AV\x00\xd6\x0033{B\n\x00-\x00ff\x9aAW\x00\xc8\x01ff\nB'

#%%
a = SubStruct()
b = MainStruct()

print('Data size: ',len(rawdata))
print('\nSubStruct:')
print('Ctype size: ',ctypes.sizeof(a))
print('Dtype size: ',np.dtype(a).itemsize)
print('\nMainStruct:')
print('Ctype size: ',ctypes.sizeof(b))
print('Dtype size: ',np.dtype(b).itemsize)

data = np.frombuffer(rawdata, dtype=MainStruct) #WRONG
```

What I expect is the following:

```
array([((0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), 87, 16.8),
       ((0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), 214, 62.8),
       ((0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 45, 19.3),
       ((1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), 456, 34.6)])
```

What I get is:

```
array([((88, 0, 87, 0, 102, 102, 134, 65), 86,  62.79999924),
       ((10, 0, 45, 0, 102, 102, 154, 65), 87,  34.59999847)])
```

Is there an efficient way to obtain the correct dtype when the ctype is available to me? Or a way to efficiently manipulate the rawdata such that I can still apply the np.frombuffer function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of numpy 1.16 ([#12254](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/12254)), this returns an error, rather than producing an incorrect result:

```
>>> data = np.frombuffer(rawdata, dtype=MainStruct)
TypeError: ctypes bitfields have no dtype equivalent
```

NumPy doesn't support bitfields, so there's no way to make this work. Your best bet is to define a replacement type that does not include bitfields, and use that instead.

If you see incorrect behavior like this in future, I'd strongly encourage you report it on the NumPy issue tracker, especially given the minimal example you have.